# Execute script every time a user login/logout using a service (gdm)

Tags: login, services, gdm

I'm a newbie in linux and I'll be glad for any help. 
I'm using gdm and I want to execute a script **every time** a user login/logout .

To see that the mechanism works, I tried at first to execute the script for login only (and not logout).
I tried to run a service that does that by adding a service under `/etc/systemd/user/serv.service`.
Below is the Unit I wrote:

```
[Unit]
Description=service

[Service]
type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/user/Documents/scriptlogin
user=user

[install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I enabled the service by `systemctl --user start serv.service`, 
and I see that the script is executed only on reboot, but not on login/logout. 
I'm not sure I understand the `default.target` line, but I'm guessing the runlevel is not changed when user logout or login, so that's why the script is not running again when logout and login again.

Does anyone know how should I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see: [How can I make a script run automatically after gdm login and logout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85985/how-can-i-make-a-script-run-automatically-after-gdm-login-and-logout)

Comment: Logout scripts can be unreliable in some circumstances: Systems may crash or suffer power outages, or the user may hold down the power button. Then the script does not run.

Comment: @Luuk Thanks. Actually that's the first thing I've tried, but we had issue with that too. Our script works when running it manually, but fail to when placed in those folders.
We asked different question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379312/gdm-logout-script-doesnt-write-to-a-file)

Comment: A, `those folders`, yep they seem to always cause a problem.... ?WTF?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a script run automatically after gdm login and logout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85985/how-can-i-make-a-script-run-automatically-after-gdm-login-and-logout)